# Slow performance MySql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying out performance of a system I'm building, and it's really slow, and I don't know why or if it should be this slow. What I'm testing is how many single INSERT I can do to the database and I get around 22 per second. That sounds really slow and when I tried to do the inserts i a singel big SQL-query I can insert 30000 records in about 0.5 seconds. In real life the inserts is made by different users in the system so the overhead of connecting, sending the query, parsing the query etc. will always be there. What I have tried so far:

- mysqli with as little code as possible. = 22 INSERT per second
- PDO with as little code as possible.    = 22 INSERT per second
- Changing the connection host from localhost to 127.0.0.1 = 22 INSERT per second
- mysqli without statement object and check for SQL-injection = 22 INSERT per second

So something seams to be wrong here.

System specs:

- Intel i5
- 16 gig ram
- 7200 rpm diskdrive

Software:

- Windows 10
- XAMPP, fairly new with MariaDB
- DB engine innoDB.

The code I used to do the tests:

```
$amountToInsert = 1000;
//$fakeData is an array with randomly generated emails 
$fakeData = getFakeData($amountToInsert); 
$db = new DatabaseHandler();
for ($i = 0; $i < $amountToInsert; $i++) {
    $db->insertUser($fakeUsers[$i]);
}
$db->closeConnection();
```

The class that calls the database:

```
class DatabaseHandler {
    private $DBHOST = 'localhost';
    private $DBUSERNAME = 'username';
    private $DBPASSWORD = 'password';
    private $DBNAME = 'dbname';
    private $DBPORT = 3306;

    private $mDb;

    private $isConnected = false;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mDb = new mysqli($this->DBHOST, $this->DBUSERNAME
                              , $this->DBPASSWORD, $this->DBNAME
                              , $this->DBPORT);
        $this->isConnected = true;
    }

    public function closeConnection() {
        if ($this->isConnected) {
            $threadId = $this->mDb->thread_id;
            $this->mDb->kill($threadId);
            $this->mDb->close();
            $this->isConnected = false;
        }
    }

    public function insertUser($user) {
        $this->mDb->autocommit(true);
        $queryString = 'INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `company_id`) '
                        .'VALUES (?, 1)';
        $stmt = $this->mDb->prepare($queryString);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return 1;
        } else {
            $stmt->close();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The "user" table has 4 columns with the following structure:

- id         INT unsigned primary key
- email      VARCHAR(60)
- company_id INT unsigned INDEX
- guid       TEXT

I'm at a loss here and don't really know where to look next. Any help in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Given your setup, 22 per second seems reasonable. Remember that every `commit` you execute *must* result in a write to disk, physical, no caching allowed. Probably even multiple writes for metadata and stuff. Doing many inserts in one transaction boosts records/second, but if that's not the real world use case scenario then it would be foolish to benchmark like that.

Comment: If this is an option for you, change the engine from *InnoDB* to *MyISAM* on this table. SInce it is the user table with not much fields and thus no frequent UPDATEs needed, it should not be an issue. INSERTs will go hell faster but there are some downsides. Only to compare your INSERTs perf results is worth a try.

Comment: If you can afford to loose the last second of transactions in case of a OS crash , then innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0 in my.ini is your friend. If you catch batch inserts into a transaction, transactions are your friend.

Comment: @JimmyB I am just curious, have you ever worked with mysql?

Comment: Just now I reproduce your code, and get 0.8 sec per 300 insertions. Same hardware and software.

Comment: @JimmyB JFYI, in last 30 years the performance of hard drives is so that you would expect reasonable speed starting from thousands inserts per second.

Comment: @YourCommonSense How, when writes are spread out across the disk, like table data, transaction log, indices &c?

Comment: @JimmyB ok, given cache is disabled, your assumption is right. But in this question there is no explicit transaction. One can dismiss `autocommit(true)` line because it is already set by default. So for a user it's just a regular write, and such a speed is not justified.

Comment: @YourCommonSense From the DBMS perspective, isn't `autocommit` exactly the same as if I'd call `commit; begin transaction;` after/before every statement?

Comment: @JimmyB exactly. But still, this is a matter whether you really need a transaction here and what speed to expect if you don't. You are right technically, but speaking of expectations, 22 wps is way too low. Nevertheless, I was wrong attacking you for which I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's explained in the comments, it's InnoDB to blame. By default this engine is too cautious and doesn't utilize the disk cache, to make sure that data indeed has been written on disk, before returning you a success message. So you basically have two options.

1. Most of time you just don't care for the confirmed write. So you can configure mysql by setting this mysql option to zero:

   ```
   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
   ```

   as long as it's set this way, your InnoDB writes will be almost as fast as MyISAM.
2. Another option is wrapping all your writes in a single transaction. As it will require only single confirmation from all the writes, it will be reasonable fast too.

Of course, it's just sane to prepare your query only once with multiple inserts but the speed gain is negligible compared to the issue above. So it doesn't count neither as an explanation nor as a remedy for *such* an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your test isn't a very good way of judging performance. Why because you are preparing a statement 1000 times. That's not the way prepared statements are supposed to be used. The statement is prepared once and different parameters bound multiple times. Try this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->mDb = new mysqli($this->DBHOST, $this->DBUSERNAME
                          , $this->DBPASSWORD, $this->DBNAME
                          , $this->DBPORT);
    $this->isConnected = true;
    $queryString = 'INSERT INTO `users`(`email`, `company_id`) '
                    .'VALUES (?, 1)';
    $this->stmt_insert = $this->mDb->prepare($queryString);

}
```

and

```
public function insertUser($user) {
    $this->stmt_insert->bind_param('s', $user);
    if ($this->stmt_insert->execute()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And, you will be seeing a huge boost in performance. So to recap, there's nothing wrong with your system, it's just the test that was bad.

**Update:**

[Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) has a point about preparing in advance and reusing the prepared statement not giving a big boost. I tested and found it to be about 5-10%

however, There is something that does give a big boost. Turning Autocommit to off!. Inserting 100 records which previously took about 4.7 seconds on average dropped to < 0.5s on average!

$con->autocommit(false);

/*loop*/
   $con->commit();

Comment: Your contributions are usually perfect, but this one is completely off the line. NOWHERE a performance boost from the multiple execution is "huge". 1-2% if you got lucky.