# java mysql Is there any way to share statement in multi-thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I'm building a RESTful server providing MYSQL query services.

The servlet is multi-thread, each thread for a request.

By default, we create a prepare-statement for a every request, but it obviously slow down the performance.

So we want to shared preparedStatement among multiple-thread.  However, the statement itself is not thread-safe. So is there any way to do this   (I hope there is some tool like a statement pool----just like connection pool that can be shared by multiple threads)

BTW, it's guaranteed that the format of SQL query is unchanged, only parameter change.

Comment: I doubt the performance hit will be on creating prepared statements.

Comment: @neomega is right. You want get a big boost: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40559212/267540

Comment: I know that preparedStatement should be reuse. However, preparedStatement is thread-unsafe, so in a multi-thread environment, I need something like a statement pool to manage

Comment: How do you manage the Threads? Do you make a new Thread for each incoming request?